# Not sure which limit screw is H vs L

Tags: derailleur

I'm using a Devinci silverstone s.1 that's having trouble getting up to the highest/largest gear on the front.

I checked the tension and it didn't seem to make a difference. Read I should check limit screws next. Mine aren't labelled H and L but I thought I could figure it out from the chain's behavior but for some reason as I tighten and loosen each one I'm not totally convinced which is which.

There's one that's higher but closer to the lower gear and one that's vice versa.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/1s19rrlvpe9foqx/file%202015-07-29%2C%2017%2040%2037.jpeg?dl=0

Comment: You can usually glimpse the part which touches the tip of the screw and thus figure out which screw is for what.

Comment: Look at the mechanism that the screws interact with.  There is a rocking arm arranged so one end moves toward it's corresponding screw when on the large sprocket and the other end moves toward the other screw when on the small sprocket.

Comment: The screw next to the seat-tube sets the limit for the big chain-ring. The other limits the derailleur for the smallest ring.

Answer (score 3):

Almost always the H limit screw is on the outside and the L limit screw is on the inside.